# Microsoft Access Query - Can't select records when adding a date to query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to compare two tables in MS Access 2010, and select records from one table (tmp_import_table) which don't exist in the second table (referrals). This works fine with the following query:

```
SELECT tmp_import_table.F2, tmp_import_table.F12, tmp_import_table.F13, tmp_import_table.RefDate
FROM tmp_import_table LEFT JOIN referrals ON tmp_import_table.[F2] = referrals.[ext_referral_no]
WHERE (((referrals.ext_referral_no) Is Null));
```

and results in the following dataset:

[image: Image showing results from initial query]

However, I now need to add a second criteria to the WHERE clause in the query, and select only records which occur after a certain date, which is stored in referrals.referral_date (date/time field) I have written the following query:

```
SELECT tmp_import_table.F2, tmp_import_table.F12, tmp_import_table.F13, tmp_import_table.RefDate
FROM tmp_import_table LEFT JOIN referrals ON tmp_import_table.[F2] = referrals.[ext_referral_no]
WHERE (((referrals.ext_referral_no) Is Null) AND ((referrals.referral_date)>#9/10/2014#));
```

But the query always ends with an empty dataset! I've tried all sorts of permutations of it, but always end up with the same empty result! In addition I've tried swearing, banging my head against the wall, and alcohol, but none of these seem to have worked either...

Can anybody spot an obvious problem with my query?

Thanks for looking!

Seb

Comment: Have you tried putting the date in American format? `#10/9/2014#`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, what is the difference between `9/10/2014` and `10/9/2014` in sense of formats?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - I've had problems before where SQL is reading UK date formats as US - so 9th October and 10th September.  Not the case here as you're solution solved the problem, but I'd advise the OP to check his dates. On a sample database `SELECT * FROM tbl_Reporting WHERE Date_Time >=#12/05/2015# ORDER BY Date_Time ASC` is returning 5th December as the earliest date (the SQL is asking for 12th May) and `SELECT * FROM tbl_Reporting WHERE Date_Time >=#05/12/2015# ORDER BY Date_Time ASC` is returning 9th September as the earliest date in my table (the SQL is asking for 5th December)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `left join` and selecting `tmp_import_table.RefDate` in the first query. But filtering by `referrals.referral_date` in the second one which may be/are `NULL`s. Change to:

```
....AND ((tmp_import_table.referral_date)>#9/10/2014#));
```

Comment: I Knew it would be something simple! Fixed! Thanks! :-)